"The jury rendered a verdict of not guilty." — "noun phrase + of + adjective phrase" is an unusual word order to me. How to parse it?
britannica.com:
(1) The jury rendered a verdict of not guilty.
"Noun phrase + of + noun phrase" is a typical construction.
But "noun phrase + of + adjective phrase" is a very strange word order to me.
my parse:
"Guilty" is an adjective.
"Not guilty" is an adjective phrase.
"Not guilty" is the complement of the preposition "of".
I find this parse strange. Is it correct?
If not, then how to parse it correctly?

my variant:
(2) The jury rendered a verdict of being not guilty.
my parse:
"Being not guilty" is a noun phrase.
"Being not guilty" is the complement of the preposition "of".
I find this parse standard.
Do you think "being" is just omitted in (1) and we must parse (1) the same way as (2)?

Could you please give me some more examples with other adjectives within the construction "noun phrase + preposition + adjective phrase" [as in (1)]?

This is just a formal wording, law tends to hold on to formalisms lost in regular language. This is particularly true, as I understand it, in US law as compared with Canada and the UK. It is a result of the precedent-based nature of these legal systems, where cases returned years (or even decades or centuries in some instances) are still relevant.

No: there is no omission of "being" in (1). *"The jury rendered a verdict of being not guilty" is ungrammatical. (1) is parsed as you say, except that the preposition phrase "of guilty is complement of the nominal "verdict" (not of the NP "a verdict").

"a verdict of not guilty" is a formal expression with regard to the verdict given by a jury in a court of law. You can't insert "being" into this. It's not idiomatic.  This is talking about the verdict itself, which is "not guilty",  not about the person "being not guilty".
